# uwp app has dynamic variables, which causes the app to crash in release mode

Tags: c#, serialization, dynamic, uwp, system.reflection

in my uwp app I am using dynamic variables at many places, because the data is coming from the server backend api, so we want to keep it dynamic. it runs fine in **Debug** mode but I wanted to upload to store so I tried it on **Release** mode and it fails with following exception

**system.reflection.missingmetadataexception**

obviously this exception occurs, in one of my pages called "LoginPage.xaml.cs" at the first line where I am trying to use the dynamic data. following is the line which causes the exception.

```
ViewModel.backgroundURL = AppConfig.Login.background;
```

> AppConfig here is a static object in a **constants** class. and its type is dynamic, I am succesfully get it from server API, but exception only occurs when I try to consume it in my app as you can see in the code line above.

after some research I found that using the following line in **Default.rd.xml** can solve this error I put the following line there.

```
<Namespace Name="bluebook.ViewModels" Seralize="All" />
```

as you can see I am putting this line in my directives tag as shown below.

```
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
    <Application>
       <!--
         An Assembly element with Name="*Application*" applies to all assemblies in
           the application package. The asterisks are not wildcards.
            -->
        <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />

        <!-- Add your application specific runtime directives here. -->
        <Namespace Name="bluebook.ViewModels" Serialize="All" />

    </Application>
</Directives>
```

> I am trying to do the directives on ViewModels because the fields I am assigning to are in the ViewModel class. I also tried to do it on **Views** name space which has all the view classes like **LoginPage** and others, but in both cases the exception is still occuring, exactly at the same line.

**Update 1**

**Exception Details**

> System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException: 'Reflection_InsufficientMetadata_NoHelpAvailable: EETypeRva:0x000a8990.
>
> StackTrace : null
>
> Source : null

Answer (score 0):

Is "Serialize" misspelled in your directive file?

Comment: No I actually wrote Serialize property, I changed the spelling. the line I pasted here was actually copied from commented out code which already is there by default in the file. and it has wrong spelling, but I corrected the spelling before running.

Comment: I have edited the question with the correct spelling, so there is no confusion about that now :)

Comment: Can you show how you are deserializing the types?  If you are using the DataContractSerializer implicitly or the XmlSerializer, you need to add those attributes to the RD directive.

Comment: I am using NewsoftJson Library for that purpose, so using method Json.Deserialize() and then I get a returned object of type dynamic and when I am trying to use the values in that dynamic object then I get the exception.

Comment: There are a number of other serialization attributes to try - intellisense in the rd.xml will show you.. Also build a debug version with the .Net native and "Enable static analysis for .NET Native" checked. This will show you warnings in the build of types that you need RD.xml directives for.

Comment: yeah I tried that but I get no warnings regarding the directives. seems strange

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<Type Name="Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpGetMemberBinder" Dynamic="Required All"/>` to your Default.rd.xml.

(This answer may be relevant to you - answered by someone who works on .Net Native - [Building with .NET Native tool chain causes error with missing property in dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175500/building-with-net-native-tool-chain-causes-error-with-missing-property-in-dynam) )

Comment: No I tried this but same error is still being caused at same place

Comment: You you look into the exception, there will be more specific details than  "system.reflection.missingmetadataexception", can you paste them here? It will reference a more specific type.

Comment: yeah I looked into the details and I have posted the details in the update section of my question

Comment: In this case, I think enabling compiling with .NET Native toolchain in DEBUG mode should give you a more informative error of what actual type information is missing. (Unless that error message info came from when running in Debug, in which case... things are difficult =P)

Comment: yeah unfortunatey still not getting any stacktrace even after enabling .net native tool chain compilation in debug mode.